# Determine if two MySQL records exist before detemining their relationship

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, sql

Imagine you have a table of Persons, Busses, and a mapping table in between. You want to determine, given a set of people, who is on a given Bus. So you create a PHP page to return a simple list of Persons. You also want the page to be robust, so you want to return any error reflected from the DB or other failures. Also, PDO is used to make the site flexible.

To reduce database queries (assuming that querying the DB is the most expensive part, especially if the DB get big and/or lots of visitors), you probably want to reduce the queries to the DB to an absolute minimum.

A simple script would, after validating the data for types and other unintended values, probably look like such on the DB side:

```
//See if the Bus exists
SELECT id FROM Busses WHERE id={$bus_id};

//See if the given Persons exist
SELECT id FROM Persons WHERE id IN ({$comma-seperated-person-ids});

//Finally check the mappings table and discover who is on that bus.
SELECT person_id FROM Busses_Persons WHERE bus_id={$bus_id} person_id IN ({$comma-seperated-ids});
```

I think this order is important, because suppose a bus did not exist, this page would return success and show an empty list if the first query did not execute to determine existing busses. You would also return a successful page with no persons, if none of the persons existed and you hadn't performed the second query to determine which of your persons set exists, and which don't. Strictly, you should return an error page if *any* provided data is invalid or non-existant.

*How can I get a list of Persons on that Bus, given a set of persons, and given a bus, **AND** find out if any given person or bus does or does not exist, and all that in a single query?*

I suppose you can hack about really deeply (even though to maintain DB abstraction with PDO, you probably can't go too far either), or it becomes a question of DB execution time. But I was really wondering how other developers made their scripts faster and more efficient when stumbling upon the problem here?

Comment: Have you considered a `JOIN` clause in the SQL?

Comment: Yes, but how does that reveal the existance of a Person or Bus ? It will just return an empty list, masking that either record doesn't exist

Comment: Just LEFT JOIN putting Busses_Persons to the left. In the select list include Busses.ID and Persons.ID. If the former is NULL Bus does not exist, if the latter - person

Comment: A full outer join will do what you need.

Comment: @Florian Mertens can you add table structure and some sample data ?

Comment: @Ashish: No, this question is about a general problem, not a specific problem. You can mock up an example structure yourself, or deduce the minimum fields from my SQL sample.

Comment: I think the problem you describe is *one* step too far in the direction of being ill-defined to support a pat answer. An 'OUTER JOIN' is likely to be used, but even in the "seemingly" simple use-case you describe, there are many possibilities in terms of a specific use-case.  The devil is in the details here, I think, so to really "get at" the general problem, I think you *need* to be more specific than you currently are. For that reason, I think it's your responsibility to provide (i.e.) a table structure, sample data, and/or sample desired output, along with an *even more specific* use-case.

Comment: CREATE TABLE Busses
(
 id BIGINT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
 strBusNumber VARCHAR(10)
);

CREATE TABLE Persons 
(
 id BIGINT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
 strName VARCHAR(20)
);

CREATE TABLE Busses_Persons 
(
 person_id BIGINT,
 bus_id BIGINT,
 PRIMARY KEY (person_id, bus_id)
);